# in VBA : create a worksheet without activate it

Tags: excel, vba

I got code which creates(copies) new sheets like:

`ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("XXX").Copy_ After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("YYY")`

and every time a new Sheet-Copy is created my Excel activates and displays the sheet.
How can I turn the auto activation off?

I want to copy new sheets and don't want to auto activate them.

Comment: The simple answer: after you finish copying , add >> ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("XXX").Activate

Comment: my problem is ..: i make a copy from Sheet (XXX) its called (`YYY) but i want to stay on Sheet (ZZZ) , i trigger the macro from there

Comment: Then  `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ZZZ").Activate`? or set a variable to the `ActiveSheet` before you copy, then `lastWorkSheet.Activate` afterwards

Comment: Adding a sheet to a workbook will always activate the new worksheet - I don't think that it is possible to deactivate this behaviour. If your intention is to have a different but the last added sheet as active sheet at the end of your procedure then you can use the provided answers. If you want to avoid flickering of the screen you can use Application.screenupdating = false (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.screenupdating)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `ActiveSheet` to an object and reactivate it again at the end of the action:

```
Sub TestMe()
    
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XXX").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YYY")
    
    wks.Activate

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    
    Rem Store The Active Sheet Into The Variable [ws] To Activate Later
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Rem Copy Your Worksheet And The New Worksheet Will Be Active
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("XXX").Copy After:=ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("YYY")
    
    Rem You Can Set Another Variable For The New Active Sheet
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    
    Rem Rename The New Copied Worksheet With Any Name You Desire
    sh.Name = "New Copy"
    
    Rem Finally Activate The First Worksheet Which Was Active
    ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: ...replace the `Rem` with the VBA comment character `'`

Comment: I suppose you could skip declaring `sh` and simply `ActiveSheet.Name = "New Copy"`?

Comment: @FunThomas what would be the difference between using rem or ' ?

Comment: @RaymondWu Yes, you are right. I used a variable supposing that there are many other lines of code that will deal with the new copied worksheet.

Comment: @YasserKhalil I am embarrassed. I work sooo long with VBA and never realized that you can use `Rem` as comment... Thought you are mixing 2 languages. My bad, sorry

Comment: Never mind my bro.